# How to limit frame rate to 30fps in OS X with Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone

I'm porting an iOS game of mine over to OS X, using Cocos2D 1.0.1 (results are the same in Cocos2D 2.0), and I'm having trouble limiting the frame rate to 30fps. Calling setAnimationInterval limits the frame rate perfectly in iOS, but does nothing in OS X (I've tried calling it everywhere, many times, etc).

```
[director setAnimationInterval:1.0/30];
```

I've also tried setTimeScale, but that doesn't limit the frame rate properly in any way. (`[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] setTimeScale:X]`)

If anyone has had any success limiting the frame rate in OS X, especially with Cocos2D, please let me know.

**Edit:**
Thank you redux. I'm already using that, actually. My apologies for not being a little clearer with my code. director is just a shortcut to the sharedDirector, as below:

```
CCDirectorMac *director = (CCDirectorMac*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
```

So the final code was still calling what the code you gave:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0/30];
```

Thanks for answering, redux. The frame rate still isn't limiting, though. Odd, since setAnimationInterval has always worked on iOS, but isn't doing anything on Mac (though the director would have been different for iOS, but still).

Comment: why limit frame rate if the game is not running slow?  Is your game logic tied to the game frame rate?

Comment: The frame rate is far, far too erratic. And yes, some of the logic is tied to the frame rate (for good reason). The game is quite large, and changing everything that relies on frames over to time would be problematic. Plus, the original worked perfectly on iOS as it is, so limiting the FPS makes the most sense for an OSX port. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that any calls to director are deprecated and need to use CCSharedDirector.  Try this:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0/30];
```